# Node.js Express route naming and ordering: how is precedence determined?

Tags: node.js, api, get, routes, express

Say I've got a few GET routes on my Express application:

```
// music albums
app.get('/api/albums', routes.albums.getAlbums);
app.get('/api/albums/:id', routes.albums.getAlbum);
app.get('/api/albums/artwork', routes.albums.getAlbumArtwork);
```

and I attempt to hit them using the follow jQuery AJAX snippet:

```
$("#retrieveAlbumArtwork").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/albums/artwork",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            artist: $("#albumArtist").val(),
            title: $("#albumTitle").val()
        },
        // ... callbacks and such
```

For some reason, this call hits the second handler, with the `/:id` parameter, instead of the explicit `/artwork` route. Swapping them like so makes them function as expected:

```
// music albums
app.get('/api/albums', routes.albums.getAlbums);
app.get('/api/albums/artwork', routes.albums.getAlbumArtwork);
app.get('/api/albums/:id', routes.albums.getAlbum);
```

Can someone explain exactly why this is happening? I would assume Express would be smart enough to identify an id param (`/albums/23453243`) versus a querystring (`/albums/artwork?artist=artistName&title=albumTitle`) and route appropriately, but this doesn't seem to be the case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No it isn't. `:id` will match anything. So `/api/albums/artwork` is totally valid for that match. Express does support RegExp match also. So you could make an explicit numeric matching route using RegExp.

Another option is using `app.param` as explained in the API documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

This allows you to define matching params for the router so you could have a URL like `/api/albums/:albumId` where `:albumId` has to be numeric, you could also validate an `albumId` at this point if you wished too.

But in all, the second way you are doing it fairly normal, generally I put static routes at the top, then dynamic routes, catch all, then error handlers.

Comment: Yep, the second way is the way TJ Holowaychuk (creator of Express) uses in his examples: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/index.js#L29