# Express route: how to differentiate between url and parameter?

Tags: node.js, express

If I have two routes:

```
app.get('/example/:param');
app.get('/example/url');
```

Is there a way to stop a request to `https://domainname.com:3000/example/url` being treated as `https://domainname.com:3000/example` with `req.params.param = "url"`

Or should I just change the route names?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to reverse the order of the `app.get` calls.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735610/node-js-express-route-naming-and-ordering-how-is-precedence-determined) for more approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)-ful and thus epxress.js will behave strangely. Change your paths so you no longer overload a path.