# HTTP endpoint not being called, endpoint with path param called instead?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

When I make a request to `http://localhost:4101/endpoint/field`, `endpoint/:id` is always logged.

Why isn't `endpoint/field` logged?

I understand that `:id` is a path parameter and can be anything, but I've explicitly said `field` should be handled differently.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 4101;

app.route('/endpoint/:id')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    console.log('endpoint/:id');
  });
app.route('/endpoint/field')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    console.log('endpoint/field');
  });

app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err on startup ' + err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Server listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of routes is important. The first valid route is used.

`/endpoint/:id` is valid for `/endpoint/field`, since :id can be anything

So you need to switch the order.

See also [Node.js Express route naming and ordering: how is precedence determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735610/node-js-express-route-naming-and-ordering-how-is-precedence-determined)