# router in express.js base on parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have these router declared in express.js, I wonder why the `run user` got triggered when I open localhost:3000/myname/profile.

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log('run user')
});

router.get('/:username/profile', function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log('run user profile')
});
```

I expect it won't,how to solve that?
please anyone help me?
Thank you in advance....

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please send the rest of the code.

Comment: really it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Just rearrange the code as shown below and your code should work fine.

```
router.get('/:username/profile', function(req, res, next)
{
   console.log('run user profile')
});

router.get('/:username', function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log('run user')
});
```

The issue is with the order in which the routes are defined, Since both the routes have `/:username` when you hit `http://localhost:3000/myname/profile.`, the first route is given preference since it matches the uri.

Also refer this stackoverflow post on express route naming and ordering - 
[Node.js Express route naming and ordering: how is precedence determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735610/node-js-express-route-naming-and-ordering-how-is-precedence-determined)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that? I tried your code and it triggered `run user profile`.May you should show the all code.