# Express.js Routing wrong route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I have 3 express.js routes

```
app.get('/packages/:name', (req, res) => {...});
app.get('/packages/search/', (req, res) => {...});
app.get('/packages/search/:name', (req, res) => {...});
```

The first and thrid routes are working just fine.
But the second route is never triggert. When I browse to "localhost/packages/search/" it will trigger the first route with `res.params.name = "search/"`

I can do an "if" to check if its "search/" but i don't think thats a good solution.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Routes are executed in the order they are defined, reverse your order.

Comment: Also consider that `/:name` will match `/search`.

Comment: because in  packages/:name  , :name is dynamic so package/search will go in packages/:name ,  move package/search on first and it will work then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes in express.js are executed in order.

For detail [Node.js Express route naming and ordering: how is precedence determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735610/node-js-express-route-naming-and-ordering-how-is-precedence-determined)